# adding more than 4 rows in a table with itextsharp give format error when creating pdf document

Tags: c#, itext

I am creating a pdf document with itextsharp. Every thing else is working fine however creation of table is giving me a headache. I am creating table dynamically and if I add more than 4 rows it gives me a format error when opening the document.

"There is an error on this page, Acrobat could not show it properly. Contact the person who created this PDF"

```
public ActionResult Createpdf()
    {
        try
        {
            ManagerInvoice mi = new ManagerInvoice();
            PDFHelper invoice = new PDFHelper();

            using (System.IO.FileStream fs = new FileStream(Server.MapPath("\\content") + "\\" + "Invoice_" + mi._Cart.Order.Invoice.InvoiceId.ToString() + ".pdf", FileMode.Create))
            {
                Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 25, 25, 30, 1);
                PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, fs);
                invoice.docHeader(document);
                document.Open();
                PdfContentByte cb = writer.DirectContent;
                int left_margin = 40;
                int top_margin = 770;                   
                cb.BeginText();                    
                top_margin = invoice.createTable(cb, document, mi._Cart, top_margin);                   
                cb.EndText();
                document.Close();
                writer.Close();
                fs.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception rror)
        {
            //lblMsg.Text = rror.Message;
        }

        return View();
    }
public int createTable(PdfContentByte cb, Document doc, Cart cart, int top_margin)
    {           
        int tableStart = top_margin;
        PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(10);
        table.TotalWidth = 530f;           
        top_margin -= 12;
        #region loop
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            GetRow(table, new Font(this.f_cn,10));
            top_margin -= 12;
        }
        #endregion
        table.WriteSelectedRows(0, -1, 40, tableStart, cb);
        return top_margin;
    }
    private void GetRow(PdfPTable t, Font f)
    {
        CMYKColor c = new CMYKColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
        t.AddCell(GetCell("Item", 1, 1, c, f));
        t.AddCell(GetCell("Description", 6, 1, c, f));
        t.AddCell(GetCell("Qty", 1, 1, c, f));
        t.AddCell(GetCell("Unit", 1, 1, c, f));
        t.AddCell(GetCell("Price", 1, 1, c, f));
    }
    private PdfPCell GetCell(string text, int colSpan, int rowSpan, CMYKColor c, Font font)
    {
        PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(text, font));
        cell.HorizontalAlignment = 0;
        cell.Rowspan = rowSpan;
        cell.Colspan = colSpan;
        cell.BackgroundColor = c;
        cell.BorderWidthLeft = 0;
        cell.BorderWidthTop = 0;
        cell.BorderWidthRight = 0;
        CMYKColor nc = new CMYKColor(0, 0, 0, 17); 
        if (c.Black == nc.Black)
            cell.BorderColor = new CMYKColor(0, 0, 0, 35);
        else
            cell.BorderColor = c;

        nc = null;

        return cell;
    }
```

Comment: Please share a sample PDF on which you observe the issue. Most likely your `cb.EndText()` and `cb.BeginText()` lines are erroneous. Why don't you simply add the partial tables to your document instead of doing all this layout'ing?

Comment: Indeed: very bad code. The use of `EndText()` and `BeginText()` should be sufficient to send the OP back to school.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0C2V5ziHuLFZDBLUlU2dHZyT00

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0C2V5ziHuLFckNLSlpkeXJWZ1E document with 4 rows open fine and document with 5 rows gives error, I have also added the code calling create table.

Comment: I have simplified the code to more generic version.

Comment: Please start by removing those `cb.EndText()` and `cb.BeginText()` lines. I don't know whether that suffices but they simply are erroneous where you use them.

Comment: thanks mkl. yes  it was cb.Begin and endText. I thought both of these method would raise an error if related object already existed. Need to read upon this lib.